# Comparison operator in for loop (C language)

Tags: c, factorial, comparison-operators

I'm trying to make basic factorial example program in C -language, but i can't understand why the following program does not function properly with == comparison operator, although it works completely fine with <= operator.

Non-functional version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i, n, fact=1;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=1; i==n; i++)
        {
            fact=fact*i;
        }

        printf("Factorial of %d is %d", n, fact);

    return 0;

}
```

Functional version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i, n, fact=1;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            fact=fact*i;
        }

        printf("Factorial of %d is %d", n, fact);

    return 0;

}
```

Thanks already in advance!

Comment: It will enter the loop only if the second statement is true. `0 == n` is false right off the bat.

Comment: There are some great answers below, but it might help your understanding a bit if you attempt to explain why you thought your initial version would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition in the for loop is a `while` condition:

```
int i = 1;
while(i == n)
{
   //loopbody
   fact=fact*i;
   i++;
}
```

So it will only do anything when `n==1`, plus the loop can only run 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 2):

The test in the `for` is checked even before the first loop

```
for (i = 1; i == 6; i++) {
    // loop will never execute as i is not 6 even before the first loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
for(i=1; i==n; i++)
```

your loop will only loop as long as `i` and `n` are equal. If you enter anything but `1` for `n` then the loop will not execute. And if you enter `1` it will only loop once as the next iteration `i` will be `2` which is no longer equal to `n`.